# Double integration using polar coordinates $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Given the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

I need to calculate the double integral for the area $A$

$A:$ $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, $y=1$

Now what I did to find my upper and lower limit is

$r=2cos(\theta)$

In parametric form I find

$\begin{cases} x=2cos^2(\theta)\\y=2sin(\theta)cos(\theta) \end{cases}$

Now for $y=1$, I got

$\frac{1}{2}=sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$ which gave me $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

$0=sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$ which gave me $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

My limits I used are {$(\theta,r)|\frac{\pi}{4}\le \theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}\le$ and $0\le r\le 2cos(\theta)$}

$\int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{2\cos \left(θ\right)}\frac{r\cos \left(θ\right)}{r\cos ^2\left(θ\right)+r\sin ^2\left(θ\right)}drdθ=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{1}{2}$

The answer in my textbook says the answer should be $\frac{2+3\pi }{4}$ which is 10 times as big as the answer I calculated, I'm not sure where I missed a factor 10.

Will somebody let me know if I made a (big) mistake because I just started with this part of calculus.

Also excuse me for my bad notation if I did.

Comment: Something is a bit fishy here, since if we have both $(x-1)^2+y^2$ and $y=1$ at the same time, then we just have the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$, and you obviously don't want $A=\{(1,1)\}$, so could you clarify what $A$ is a bit more?

Comment: To do a Euclidean area calculation in polar coordinates, the correct area element is $r \, dr \, d\theta$, not $dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: What is the integration region? Does it include any axis?

Comment: Oh my god, I read my problem wrong, it should've been $y=x$ instead of $y=1$, I'm sorry.